# Creating a cursor, Is the data being copied?

Tags: database, oracle, cursor

I'm working with cursors at the moment and it's getting messy for me, hope you can highlight some questions to me.

I have checked the oracle documentation about cursors but I cannot find out:

When a cursor is opened, is a local copy of the result created on memory?

- Yes: Does it really make sense if I have a table with lot of data? I think it would not be really efficient, isn't it?.
- No:
  Is the whole data locked to other processes?

  1. YES
     : What if I'm doing a truly heavy process for each row, the data would be unavaliable for so long...
  2. NO
     : What would happen if another process modify the data I'm currently using with the cursor or if it adds new rows, would it be updated for the cursor?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Cursor while sometimes the only way you can go, are always inefficient. There are several varieties of cursor from forward only read, to fully synchronised, the more you need from it the more it costs. It's always better to put the effort into not needing a cursor (except for one off admin tasks), than to try make the best cursor you can.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - how do you access data in a relational database without using a cursor?

Comment: Select statement... Depends on what you are doing with the cursor, but many problems can be addressed via schema changes, course that isn't always an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read the section on [Data Concurrency and Consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#i13945) in the [Concepts Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/toc.htm).

The answers to your specific questions:

> When a cursor is opened, is a local copy of the result created on
>   memory?

No, however via Oracle's "Multiversion Read Consistency" (see link above) the rows fetched by the cursor will all be consistent with the point in time at which the cursor was opened - i.e. each row when fetched will be a row that existed when the cursor was opened and still has the same values (even though another session may have updated or even deleted it in the mean time).

> No: Is the whole data locked to other processes?

No

> NO : What would happen if another process modify the data I'm currently using with the cursor or if it adds new rows, would it be updated for the cursor?

Your cursor would not see those changes, it would continue to work with the rows as they existed when the cursor was opened.

The Concepts Guide explains this in detail, but the essence of the way it works is as follows:

- Oracle maintains a something called a [System Change Number (SCN)](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/scn.html) that is continually incremented.
- When your cursor opens it notes the current value of the SCN.
- As the cursor fetches rows it looks at the SCN stamped on them.  If this SCN is the same or lower than the cursor's starting SCN then the data is up to date and is used.  However if the row's SCN is higher that the cursor's then this means that another session has changed the row (and committed the change).  In this case Oracle looks in the rollback segments for the old version of the row and uses that instead.  If the query runs for a long time it is possible that the old version has been overwritten in the rollback segments.  In this case the query fails with an ORA-01555 error.

You can modify this default behaviour if needed.  For example, if it is vital that no other session modifies the rows you are querying during the running of your cursor, then you can use the `FOR UPDATE` clause to lock the rows:

```
CURSOR c IS SELECT sal FROM emp FOR UPDATE OF sal;
```

Now any session that tries to modify a row used in your query while it is running is blocked until your query has finished you commit or rollback.